# Load the big array in one time and use the loaded in everywhere

Tags: php, arrays, information-retrieval

I am coding simple search engine (using vector model) and I have a big text file with indexes. In my application, I have to load the file and convert it to an array

At this moment, I create new instance of class in every page, which loads this file to the array.

Can I load this array only once (at the beginning) and then use the loaded one, which is written in RAM, I suppose?

Comment: The most sensible solution here would be to use a database, allowing access to every fields. It allows for partial data retrieval which cannot be achieved using a flat file.

Comment: What do you mean by 'beginning'?

Comment: It could be some script which is launched manually or something like that. (it's a school project, so i'm not thinking about cron)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer; Yes!

There are several options you can use. PHP has a library called [APC](https://www.php.net/apc)

You can do something like this...

[apc_store](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php) and [apc_fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-fetch.php)

```
<?php
$bar = 'BAR';
// store variable $bar in memory for 1 hour with key 'foo'
apc_store('foo', $bar, 3600);
var_dump(apc_fetch('foo'));
?>
```

---

Here's a proper use case example:

*This automatically deals with expired cache and re-loads cache.*

```
<?php

// Config?
define('CACHE_LIFESPAN', 3600); // 1 Hour

// Helper Function
function loadXYZData() {
    $result = @apc_fetch(__FUNCTION__);
    if (!$result) {
        $result = array('a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd'); // dummy data
        @apc_store(__FUNCTION__, $result, CACHE_LIFESPAN);
    }
    return $result;
}

// Usage - through out all your scripts
$myXYZData = loadXYZData();
var_dump($myXYZData);

?>
```

Here, the APC cache uses the function name as the cache key. So, you will be creating a function similar to the above per cacheable data in your application.

Above script's output is:

```
array (size=2)
  'a' => string 'b' (length=1)
  'c' => string 'd' (length=1)
```

---

Beyond APC, there are third party key value pair storage engine (in memory) like Memcached: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php

There are others, if you look around.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that the data needed will persist in RAM between PHP calls using these methods?

Comment: correct. the data will be in memory until the TTL expires and the data is cleared. Let me update my answer with a better example.

Comment: It sounds simply, i'll try it, thanks :) I will write result then.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a proper use case example.

Comment: It works, but i have problem with bigger arrays (about 50 000 keys) Is there some limit or maximum?

Comment: what kind of problem are you facing with 50,000 records? slow? not loading? any error? not enough memory? P.S. Have you configured your APC correctly? Try using a config like this: http://pastebin.com/ZthBYcPN (be sure to adjust the `apc.shm_size` to your desired size. this is how much memory you are allocating to the shared memory of apc module).